# Upper bound on $E\left(\left.P\left(X>\frac{Y}{Y+\delta}\right| Y\right)\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Suppose $X,Y$ are independent nonnegative random variables and $\delta>0$ is a constant. I am interested in a general upper bound on 
$$
E\left(\left.P\left(X>\frac{Y}{Y+\delta}\right| Y\right)\right).
$$
Using the conditional Markov inequality one would get 
$$
E(X)E\left(\frac{Y+\delta}{Y}\right),
$$
which is problematic if the expectation of the reciprocal of $Y$ is not well defined. Does anyone have a better idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get from
$$
E\left(\left.P\left(X>\frac{Y}{Y+\delta}\right| Y\right)\right)
$$ 
to
$$
P\left(X>\frac{Y+\delta}{Y}\right).
$$
The fraction seems to be inverted?

Comment: Right, what I meant is that the conditional aspect is misleading, you are simply after an upper bound of $$P\left(X>\frac{Y}{Y+\delta}\right)=P\left(X\cdot(Y+\delta)>Y\right)=P\left((X-1)\cdot Y+\delta\cdot X>0\right)$$